# How to access libs locally in nixos?

Tags: linux, python, libraries

I am using nixOS for a little time, but coming from Ubuntu I have a hard time with binary dependencies. My problem is that I want to install psycopg2 in a virtualenv. This package is not a pure-python one and it links to postgres binaries. So when I try to install the package I get:

```
./psycopg/psycopg.h:31:22: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
```

The question is - how to make the binary libs and header files available for local installations like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For python development I usually use combination of `nix-shell` and `virtualenv` configuration.

```
% nix-shell -p pythonPackages.virtualenv postgresql
(nix-shell) % virtualenv env
(nix-shell) % ./env/bin/pip install psycopg2
```

Important part above is you install `postgresql` alongside virtualenv

Some packages, like Pillow, make too much assumptions where libraries should be and you might need to use it from `pythonPackages` directly.

You might be also interested into [pypi2nix](https://github.com/garbas/pypi2nix) which can convert your `requirements.txt` file to nix expressions. if you get stuck with it please ping me on irc, I'd love to get it tested.